# Filter JavaScript Object by value

Tags: javascript

I have this object array:

```
var result = [
{
    appAddress:"127.0.0.1",
    name:"AppServer1",
    dbConnection:""
},
{
    appAdress:"",
    name:"DBServer1",
    dbConnection:"Server=.;Database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"
}];
```

Now i need to get only the name values (into an array), where the appAddress isn't empty. I tried *array.filter()* and *$.map()* but none of these methods seems to do what i want.

This is what i tried:

```
var appServers = $.map(result, function (val, key) {
    return (key == 'appAddress' && val.length > 0) ? key : null;
    });
```

and

```
var appServers = result.filter(function (entry) {
    return entry['displayName'];
    });
```

Comment: Just an array of strings.

Comment: Show what you have tried. And this is quite a simple task to do yourself. Just loop the array, check the `appAddress`, if it's NOT empty, `push` it on to a new array that contains the results.

Comment: What did you try? What happened? `.filter()` and `.map()` are exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for showing what you've tried. Your problem with your use of `$map` is that you expect it to iterate over the properties of each object, but it does not: it iterates over the array. `key` will never be `"appAddress"`, because `$.map` is operating on an array (which only has key names like `0`, `1`, `2`, etc..), not the objects inside that array. As shown in Matthias's answer, you should use the first argument (`val`) to access each object and `val.appAddress`/`val.name` to get its property values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filtering you can use `filter` and `map` methods of `Array`. See the below example.

**[Array.prototype.filter Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

**[Array.prototype.map Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

```js
var result = [{
  appAdress: "127.0.0.1",
  name: "AppServer1",
  dbConnection: ""
}, {
  appAdress: "",
  name: "DBServer1",
  dbConnection: "Server=.;Database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"
}];


// First Solution
var out = result.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.appAdress;
}).map(function(obj) {
  return obj.name;
})

// Second Solution
var namesArr = [];
result.forEach(function(obj) {
  if (obj.appAdress) {
    namesArr.push(obj.name);
  }
});



document.querySelector('#out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(out, undefined, 4);
document.querySelector('#out2').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(namesArr, undefined, 4);
```

```html
First Solution
<pre id="out"></pre>

<hr/>

Second Solution
<pre id="out2"></pre>
```

Comment: @musefan see the updated implementation. i have added map after filter.

Comment: This (first Solution) worked for me. First i need to filter and then map exposes the single object value. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First off, your object definitions are wrong. You need to use `:` instead of `=`.

Next, you can do this with a simple for loop:

```
var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var item = result[i];
    if (item.appAddress) output.push(item.name);
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/t3eqxjbw/)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could probably do is

```
var names = result.filter(
    function (t) {
        return t.appAddress != "";
}).map(
    function (t) {
        return t.name;
});
```

Comment: Missed that part of the question X.X updated my answer.

Comment: Better to format your answer as code (4 spaces), rather that quote ( > )

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce like this:

```js
var result = [
    {
        appAdress: "127.0.0.1",
        name: "AppServer1",
        dbConnection: ""
    },
    {
        appAdress: "",
        name: "DBServer1",
        dbConnection: "Server=.;Database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    }];

var addresses = result.reduce(function (acc, it) {
    if (it.appAdress) {
        acc.push(it.name);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(addresses);
```

```html
Please check the result in console.
```

Comment: I keep forgetting about reduce +1

Answer (score 0):

The objects defined in your `result` array are not valid. Object values are written as `name:value` pairs (separated by a colon).

Try this:

```js
var result = [{
  appAdress: "127.0.0.1",
  name: "AppServer1",
  dbConnection: ""
}, {
  appAdress: "",
  name: "DBServer1",
  dbConnection: "Server=.;Database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"
}];

var resultArr = $.map(result, function(val, i) {
  if (val.appAdress.length > 0) return val.name;
});

console.log(resultArr);
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Run on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/La183bck/2/) or read more about [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/).